# Transposing records to column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title might not even be the right thing I'm looking for but looking for some other ideas on how to query things.

I have the following tables:

```
items (itemID, upc, name)
levels (levelID, desc)
levelGrp (levelGrpID, levelID, desc)
levelGrp_Intersection (itemID, levelID, levelGrpID)
```

levels table would have just 3 records:

```
  { 1, Department }
, { 2, Category }
, { 3, Sub-Category }
```

levelGrp table defines descriptions that has the right level:

```
  { 545, 1, Beverages }
, { 546, 2, Alcohol }
, { 547, 3, Beer }
```

So you can see the correlation. One department is called Beverages one Category is called Alcohol and one sub-category is called Beer.

Now the levelGrp_Intersection table will add an item for each so you'd have:

```
{ 100, 1, 545 }
{ 100, 2, 546 }
{ 100, 3, 547 }
```

So this says:

```
item 100 has its Department as Beverages
item 100 has its Category as Alcohol
item 100 has its Sub-Category as Beer
```

The question now is querying this. If I want to see what the Department, Category, and Sub-Category are for each item what's the best way.

I know I can do subselects in the select statement to get this information but subselects are generally considered bad (from my understanding) so what are my other options?

Ideally I'd want just 1 row for each item and we'd be creating columns for Department, Category, Sub-Category which are really records in a table. It's like we're taking these records and converting them to columns. Not that levelGrp has about 700+ records so pivoting on that isn't really an option **and no dynamic sql.**

Any ideas?

Comment: no pivot, no dynamic = no donut. Can you pivot it on the caller application? And what sql server version?

Comment: 2012. No pivot on the caller app. The data that returns from a proc that does this simply passes the data along as is no exception. Maybe a pivot can be done? I mean we are hard coding the levels (1, 2, 3) when looking but that joins to levelGrp which just has too many records (700+) and we don't want to hard code those values, but maybe the pivoting happens on the 1, 2, 3 values and we get the description from the levelGrp table? I just can't think of how that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation with known level names:

```
select
    lgi.item
  , Department  = max(case when levelid = 1 then lg.[desc] end)
  , Category    = max(case when levelid = 2 then lg.[desc] end)
  , Subcategory = max(case when levelid = 3 then lg.[desc] end)
from levelGrp_Intersection lgi
  inner join levelGrp lg
    on lg.levelGrpId = lgi.levelGrpID
group by lgi.item
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!